# How to do these two integral questions?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

First question:

[image: first question]

I try to use partial fraction to separate the rational function ( I don't know if I am in the right direction). However, I am still stuck.

Second quesiton:

I need to find the area between the loop of the function $$y^2=x^2(x+3)$$  My strategy is to make it $y=\sqrt{x^2(x+3)}$ , find the integral of this and then multiply by two. However, I cannot find the integral.

Comment: For the second question I would make a new post since it is not related to your first question.. For the first question, Indeed you should perform partial fraction decomp. Your denominators are $x+1$ and $x^2-2x+6$ with  numerators $A$ and  $Bx+C$ respectively. Can you try this?

Comment: Yes I tried this, and the result still has a part -(27x-45)/(x^2-2x+6) that I need to integrate, and here is the part I stuck.

Comment: As one answer below shows, "create" the derivative of the non factorable denominator into the numerator. That ultimately leads to a $ln$ and an $arctan$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, rewrite:
$$\frac{81}{(x+1)(x^2-2x+6)} = 
\frac{9}{x+1} + \frac{9(x-1)}{x^2-2x+6} - \frac{18}{x^2-2x+6}$$
Then the integration should be easy.

For the second one, your integral is:
$\int_{-3}^0 2 \sqrt{x(x^2 + 3)}$.
Use substitution, $u = \sqrt{x+3}, du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+3}}$, then your new integral is:
$$4\int_0^{\sqrt{3}} (u^4 - 3u^2) du$$